# Force PC to calculate equation to infinite decimal places?

Tags: command-line

I need a software or a command line to display the irrational number `22/7` indefinitely.

When i use `calc`, I'm shown a finite number of decimal places:

```
~$ calc 22/7
~3.14285714285714285714
```

How can I force my PC to calculate forever?

Comment: Do you want to know more digits of 22/7 or do you just want to computer to calculate any number?

Comment: I can search google for more, but it's a homework, so I need the code or an app

Comment: Is there a limit? Do you know any programming languages?

Comment: This is hard, does it never repeat? I can paste it here: 3.142857142857142793701541449991054832935333251953125 is to 51 dp, thats about as long as you can get I think, as on a 64 bit computer to do with limits of accuracy...

Comment: I dont rly know any programming languages :(

Comment: My Pc is 64 bit but  I use 32 bit version of Ubuntu, is it a problem?

Comment: No, I will quickly look into it for you, I may be able to find a good method.

Answer (score 3):

```
bc <<< 'scale=100;22/7'
```

bc is Best Calculator and is normally installed on ubuntu

`scale=<num>` means the number of digits you want after the comma
`22/7` you calculation

found here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers